# How is the Allee effect modeled in the presence of a highly variable carrying capacity?

Tags: theoretical-biology, population-dynamics

Consider a rather standard model of population dynamics in the presence of a strong Allee effect:
$$ \frac{du}{dt}=u\left(1-\frac{u}{K}\right)\left(\frac{u}{A}-1\right),$$
where $u(t)$ is population, $K>0$ is carrying capacity, and $A>0$ is the Allee threshold---the population below which the species, for one reason or another, cannot survive (for example, a social species which relies on being in large groups for survival).

Now suppose that the carrying capacity is also changing in time: $K=K(t)$. Let us suppose that it is varying in a given, predetermined way due to, e.g., climate change. If $K(t)$ remains larger than $A$ for all $t$, then this model remains acceptable to study population dynamics. But if eventually, $K(t)<A$, then for $K(t)<u<A$, we actually have $\frac{du}{dt}>0$, despite $u$ being both above the carrying capacity and below the Allee threshold. Obviously, this model for population dynamics is no longer relevant in this regime.

It seems that a solution to this problem would be to use the model
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\begin{cases} u\left(1-\frac{u}{K}\right)\left(\frac{u}{A}-1\right) & K>A\\  F(u;K,A) & K\leq A,\end{cases}$$
where $F(0)=0$ and $F(u;K,A)<0$ for all $u>0$ whenever $K<A$ is chosen so that the right hand side of the above ODE is smooth or at least continuous in $K$. My questions are:

1. Has this been studied in the math biology literature?
2. If so, is a solution similar to mine proposed?
3. If so, what is the function $F$ that is used?

Comment: this maybe of interest https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/332/1/012051/pdf

Comment: @RoniSaiba That is interesting, thanks.